# How to work around Azure App Setting Key Length Limitation

Tags: azure

I am finding that all of my Azure App Setting keys are getting truncated to 64 characters in my application when I try to access them as environment variables.  I have only found one website that documents this behavior.  Every other website claims I should have a 10KB limit for the key/value together, so I am very confused about this rule to begin with.

My question is how can I work around this limitation?  I use these app settings the way I thought Microsoft intended me to as configuration keys, but 64 characters is no where near long enough.  I never encountered any kind of limitations like this with PCF.

64 Character Limit:
[64 Character Limit Documentation](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux/ba-p/392472#EnvLimit)

10 KB Limit:
[10 KB Limit Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/faq)

Edit:
I got a question asking why my keys would be 64 characters, so let me explain.  The .Net Core Configuration components allow you to declare configuration in json files and then override or augment those values using App Settings.  It doesn't take too many levels of nested configuration objects to go over the 64 character limit.

Json File Containing:

```
{
    "ParentConfiguration": {
         "NestedConfiguration": "Value1"
    }
}
```

Can override with App Setting named "ParentConfiguration__NestedConfiguration"

Comment: the 10KB link you posted is for the Azure App Configuration Service, not for App Service settings. But: what kind of keys are you using that 64 is not enough? :)